# String assignment with initializer lists

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

- Can you explain me, why are there differences?
- What's mean `PKcE`?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s {"IDE"};
    std::cout<<typeid(s).name()<<std::endl;

    auto S{"IDE"};      // why do not deduced as string?
    std::cout<<typeid(S).name()<<std::endl;

    auto c = {"IDE"};  // why do not deduced as string?
    std::cout<<typeid(c).name()<<std::endl;   

    auto C {string{"IDE"}}; // why do not deduced as string?
    std::cout<<typeid(C).name()<<std::endl; 

    auto Z = string{"IDE"};
    std::cout<<typeid(Z).name()<<std::endl; 

}
```

output:

```
Ss
St16initializer_listIPKcE
St16initializer_listIPKcE
St16initializer_listISsE
Ss
```

Comment: The names returned by [`std::type_info::name`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name) are compiler dependent. You should not really use them for anything.

Comment: As for your problems (I think) *why* should the type-deduced variables not be deduced as [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list)? You do use an `std::initializer_list` in the initialization.

Comment: `c++filt -t St16initializer_listIPKcE` gives `std::initializer_list<char const*>`

Comment: With N3922 `auto S{"IDE"};` will be deduced as `const char*`, and `auto C {string{"IDE"}};` will be deduced as `std::string`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
string s {"IDE"};  // Type of s is explicit - std::string

auto S{"IDE"};     // Type of S is an initializer list consisting of one char const*.

auto c = {"IDE"};  // Type of c is same as above.

auto C {string{"IDE"}}; // Type of C is an initializer list consisting of one std::string

auto Z = string{"IDE"}; // Type of Z is std::string
```

I don't know what `PKcE` stands for. I can only guess that `P` stands for Pointer, `K` stands for const, `c` stands for character. No clue what `E` could stand for.

Comment: Good guesses, they're all correct. And `I`...`E` simply marks the template argument list.